# How to use the explode function in PHP using 2 delimeters instead of 1?

Tags: php, explode

Suppose I have the following:

```
$string = "(a) (b) (c)";
```

How would I explode it to get the contents inside the parenthesis. If the string's contents were separated by just one symbol instead of 2 I would have used:

```
$string = "a-b-c";
explode("-", $string);
```

But how to do this when 2 delimiters are used to encapsulate the items to be exploded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) or [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) instead.

Example:

```
$string = "(a) (b) (c)";
print_r(preg_split('/\\) \\(|\\(|\\)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
```

Notice the order is important.

Comment: Hi, not very good at writing the regular expression rule needed to go inside the preg split function. How would that go to match the contents inside the ()?

Answer (score 4):

If there is no nesting parenthesis, you can use regular expression.

```
$string = "(a) (b) (c)";
$res = 0;
preg_match_all("/\\(([^)]*)\\)/", $string, $res);
var_dump($res[1]);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
```

See http://www.ideone.com/70ZlQ

Answer (score 3):

If you know for a fact that the strings will always be of the form `(a) (b) (c)`, with precisely one space between each pair of parentheses and with no characters at the beginning or end, you can avoid having to use regexp functions:

```
$myarray = explode(') (', substr($mystring, 1, -1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
<?php
  $s="Welcome to (London) hello ";    
  $data = explode('(' , $s );    
  $d=explode(')',$data[1]);    
  print_r($data);    
  print_r($d);    
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Welcome to [1] => London) hello )
Array ( [0] => London [1] => hello )
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use preg_split with an alternation pattern:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

If your delimiters are consistent like that, then you can do this

```
$string = "(a) (b) (c)";
$arr = explode(") (", $string);
// Then simply trim remaining parentheses off.
$arr[0] = trim($arr[0], "()");
end($arr) = trim($arr[0], "()");
```

Comment: Good point! Either way though, the OP can still explode on ") (" and get what he needs.